# c# MVC always running thread?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

First, I apologize in advance if this is a duplicate question.

I wrote a windows service (c# .net 4.7) that creates a TcpClient connection to my alarm panel and listens for incoming data and then forwards the data to a website that I use to connect other services to. For reliability, I want to port this functionality to a c# MVC website so I can monitor it's state (make sure it's still connected, alarm hasn't gone off, etc).

I started out creating a MVC project & in the global.asax file, I kick off a new thread that loads/runs the class I originally created for the winService.

```
Application["MyTcpClass"] = new MyTcpClass();
```

Then in my HomeController, I added a Poll() ActionResult:

```
    public void Poll()
    {
        MyTcpClass objClass = (MyTcpClass)Application["MyTcpClass"];
        //If objClass is null, recreate/reconnect it
        objClass.Poll();
    }
```

Before I go any further and start adding a way to return statuses, etc, I wanted to check with everyone to see if this is a good method and/or if there's a better way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "I kick off a new thread" nope, not a good idea. Don't create your own threads in ASP.NET.

Comment: agreed, and i know creating background tasks/threads/jobs in asp.net is sort of out of the scope of what asp.net can do,but i need this TCP connection to be as close to permanent as possible (part of the Poll() actionresult is to reconnect if it got disconnected)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to keep a custom `TcpClient` open in the background, you're better off keeping it as a Windows service. ASP.NET will just complicate it.

For one (assuming you'll host it in IIS), IIS will, by default, shut off websites if they haven't gotten any incoming requests in 20 minutes. You can turn that behaviour off entirely, but it's still unreliable to expect IIS to keep your application running 100% of the time. Websites are designed to respond to HTTP requests, not to run background tasks.

If you want to make a website where you can check what your service is doing, then one way to do that is to use [`HttpListener`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/httplistener) in your service to make a web service that your web application can call. I've done this before in a project I worked on. There's an example of how to use it here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/599978/An-HttpListener-Server-for-Handling-AJAX-POST-Requ

*Update:* I found that example too busy, so I created my own based on the past project I did: http://www.gabescode.com/dotnet/2018/11/01/basic-HttpListener-web-service.html

Comment: Thanks Gabriel - the HttpListener "webserver" you linked to is similar to the code I wrote for the windows service. What I'm looking for is if/how to port it to a asp.net/MVC website. What's the difference between a webpage that launches a class/object in a new thread different than a webservice?

Comment: @Losbear Webpages and webservices aren't different in that sense - the difference is in how you host it. Gabriel suggests hosting the web interface in a windows service, where you can control the lifetime of any threads etc.. IIS is the problem, not MVC (strictly speaking).

Comment: I'm suggesting you have two parts: 1. Your Windows service that does your background tasks *and* has a web service, and 2. A website (like ASP.NET MVC) that communicates with your Windows service via the web service.

Comment: @Luaan has the right idea. It's just IIS that's the problem. It controls the processes for each website it hosts, so it's difficult to guarantee that your application will always be running in the background.

Comment: I get everything you guys are saying re: IIS, etc.  I was really trying to avoid having a windows service that runs locally in case something happened to the computer that it's running on. Was thinking a 3rd party monitoring service pinging this website i want to create would keep it alive (about once every minute).  But it may be the only way to get this to work reliably.